# What is this sparrow framework in iphone development?

Tags: frameworks, iphone-sdk-3.0, sparrow-framework

I am new in iphone development .I recently heard about a sparrow framework which is used to create games for iphone but i could not get more knowledge about this framework.Is it an apple framework ? Do it provide some special features to iphone game developement?

Comment: Does http://www.sparrow-framework.org/ not answer your question?  More specifically http://www.sparrow-framework.org/info/features/.

Comment: @nick-the site only says its easy and nothing more

Answer (score 2):

It's an open-source project, therefore it doesn't belong to Apple. I basically use the OpenGL library and provide you a very easy to use abstraction of it. So it doesn't provide any features, but makes the development simple games much easier. Give it a try!

Comment: You will? You mean... later? I'm looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

The nicest thing about Sparrow's API is that it is very similar to Adobe Flash. So if you have programmed Flash games before, it will be very easy to learn Sparrow. I have already published two games with Sparrow, and it was very nice to work with.